# Unable to start postgres unless I type the command to restart it

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, startup, postgresql, settings

Whenever I try to start my project the following error occurs.

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

This is the status of postgres:

```
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
  Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: inactive (dead)
```

And it will only work when I restart the service, how can I avoid restarting it every time I turn on my laptop could it be that the installation is wrong?

I'm using Ubuntu 18

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output you showed from `systemctl status postgresql` indicates that it is "disabled", meaning it will not start by default:

> Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; **disabled;**

Enable the service to let it start at boot:

```
sudo systemctl enable postgresql
```